# How can I pass a variable between angularjs views?

Tags: angularjs

I have a .slim file with AngularJS code. In this file, there's different views.

In the `upload` view, I have two radio buttons and I would like to keep the value of the radio selected in my `edit` view.

I read that I need a service, but I don't know Angular (and i'm pretty bad with javascript) so it's a bit difficult to understand and know what I have to do...

This is my whole view:

```
.gr-picture-upload-modal.modal.fade data-backdrop="static"
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content data-ng-controller="PictureUploadCtrl" data-ng-if="view == 'upload'"
      .modal-header
        button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="cancel()" &times;
        h4.modal-title= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.title')
      .modal-body.picture-upload
        .picture-upload-dropbox data-ng-model="files" data-ngf-drop=true data-ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'" data-ngf-multiple="true" data-ngf-allow-dir="false" data-accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png,image/gif,image/bmp"
          = t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.drag_and_drop_or')
          button type="button" class="btn-link" data-ngf-select="true" data-ng-model="files" data-ngf-multiple="true" data-accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png,image/gif,image/bmp"
            = t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.select')
          = t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.one_or_more_image')
        p.picture-upload-hint= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.hints')
      .list-group.picture-upload-list-group data-ng-show="pictures.length > 0"
        .list-group-item data-ng-repeat="picture in pictures"
          .row
            .col-xs-8
              img.picture-upload-thumbnail data-ngf-src="picture" alt="{{picture.name}}"
              span.picture-upload-filename data-ng-hide="picture.upload.aborted || picture.errors" data-ng-bind="picture.name"
              span.picture-upload-error.text-warning data-ng-show="picture.upload.aborted"= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.upload_aborted')
              span.picture-upload-error.text-danger data-ng-show="picture.errors" data-ng-bind="picture.errors[0]"
            .col-xs-3
              .progress.picture-upload-progress data-ng-show="picture.progress >= 0"
                .progress-bar data-ng-class="progressClass(picture)" style="width:{{picture.progress}}%;"
            .col-xs-1
              button.btn-link.picture-upload-abort type="button" title=t('views.application.buttons.cancel') data-ng-hide="picture.upload == null || picture.progress == 100 || picture.upload.aborted" data-ng-click="picture.upload.abort();picture.upload.aborted=true" &times;
      .modal-footer data-ng-show="pictures.length > 0"
        div data-ng-if="successUpload > 0"
          .row
            .col-xs-4
              p.pull-left= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.position')
              .radio-inline
                label
                  input type="radio" ng-model="position" value="first"= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.first_position')
              .radio-inline
                label
                  input type="radio" ng-model="position" value="last"= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.last_position')
            .col-xs-8
              button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-ng-disabled="uploading != 0" data-ng-click="editView()"= t('views.application.buttons.done')
        div data-ng-if="successUpload == 0"
          a.btn.btn-primary.pull-right href="" data-ng-class="{'disabled': (uploading != 0)}" data-ng-click="done('#{user_pictures_path(current_user.username)}')"
            = t('views.application.buttons.done')

    .modal-content data-ng-if="view == 'edit'"
      .modal-header
        .btn-toolbar.pull-right
          .btn-group
            button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-disabled="navIndex <= 0 || loading" data-ng-click="prevPicture()"
              span.icon.icon-arrow-left
            button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-disabled="navIndex >= (pictures.length - 1) || loading" data-ng-click="nextPicture()"
              span.icon.icon-arrow-right
          a.btn.btn-default href="" data-ng-class="{'disabled': loading}" data-ng-click="done('#{user_pictures_path(current_user.username)}')"
            = t('views.application.buttons.done')
        h4.modal-title #{t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.new_image')} ({{navIndex + 1}}/{{pictures.length}})
      .modal-body
        form data-ng-submit="update(editPicture)"
          .container-fluid
            .row
              .col-xs-12.col-md-4
                .thumbnail.picture-upload-edit-thumbnail data-ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url(' + editPicture.image.thumbnail + ')'}"
              .col-xs-12.col-md-8
                .form-group data-ng-class="{'has-error': editPicture.errors['title']}"
                  label.control-label for="picture_title"= t('picture.labels.title')
                  input.form-control type="text" id="picture_title" name="picture[title]" data-ng-model="editPicture.title" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50"
                  span.help-block data-ng-bind="editPicture.errors['title'][0]"
                .form-group data-ng-class="{'has-error': editPicture.errors['category_id']}"
                  label.control-label for="picture_category_id"= t('picture.labels.category')
                  - cache('categories._picture_upload_modal.select_tag', skip_digest: true) do
                    = select_tag 'category', options_for_select(Category.order(name: :asc).all.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }), id: 'picture_category_id', class: 'form-control', include_blank: true, data: { ng_model: 'editPicture.category_id' }
                  span.help-block data-ng-bind="editPicture.errors['category_id'][0]"
            .form-group data-ng-class="{'has-error': editPicture.errors['description']}"
              label.control-label for="picture_description"= t('picture.labels.description')
              textarea.form-control id="picture_description" name="picture[description]" data-ng-model="editPicture.description" maxlength="800"
              span.help-block data-ng-bind="editPicture.errors['description'][0]"
            .form-group  data-ng-class="{'has-error': editPicture.errors['tags_string']}"
              label.control-label for="picture_tags_string" = t('picture.labels.tags_string')
              input.form-control type="text" id="picture_tags_string" name="picture[tags_string]" data-ng-model="editPicture.tags_string" autocomplete="off" placeholder=t('picture.placeholders.tags_string')
              span.help-block data-ng-bind="editPicture.errors['tags_string'][0]"
            .form-group data-ng-class="{'has-error': editPicture.errors['license']}"
              label.control-label for="picture_license"= t('picture.labels.license')
              = select_tag 'license', options_for_select(t('picture.labels.licenses').collect { |k, v| [v, k] }), id: 'picture_license', class: 'form-control', include_blank: true, data: { ng_model: 'editPicture.license' }
              span.help-block data-ng-bind="editPicture.errors['license'][0]"
            .btn-toolbar.pull-right
              button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" data-ladda="loading" data-style="expand-right"= t('helpers.submit.submit')
              button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'disabled': loading}" data-ng-show="navIndex >= (pictures.length - 1)"
                = link_to t('views.application.buttons.done'), URI::unescape(user_pictures_path(current_user.username, picturesNb: '{{pictures.length}}', position: '{{position}}'))
```

This is my radio buttons:

```
.radio-inline
                label
                  input type="radio" ng-model="position" value="first"= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.first_position')
              .radio-inline
                label
                  input type="radio" ng-model="position" value="last"= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.last_position')
```

And this is where I want the value of the radio selected:

```
button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'disabled': loading}" data-ng-show="navIndex >= (pictures.length - 1)"
                = link_to t('views.application.buttons.done'), URI::unescape(user_pictures_path(current_user.username, picturesNb: '{{pictures.length}}', position: '{{position}}'))
```

Also, this is my controller:

```
App.controller 'PictureUploadCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Upload', 'newPictures', ($scope, $rootScope, Upload, newPictures)->

  $scope.pictures      = []
  $scope.uploading     = 0
  $scope.successUpload = 0
  $scope.position      = 'last'

  $scope.$watch 'files', (files)->
    if files and files.length
      for file in files
        $scope.pictures.push(file)
        $scope.upload file
    null

  $scope.upload = (picture)->
    $scope.uploading += 1
    picture.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: '/pictures',
      data: { picture: { image: picture }}
    }).progress((event)->
      picture.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * event.loaded / event.total))
    ).success((data, status, headers, config)->
      picture.id = data.picture.id
      newPictures.add(data.picture)
      $scope.uploading -= 1
      $scope.successUpload += 1
    ).error((data, status, headers, config)->
      if data is null
        null
      else if data.errors.base?
        picture.errors = data.errors.base
      else if data.errors.image?
        picture.errors = data.errors.image
      else if data.errors.image_fingerprint?
        picture.errors = data.errors.image_fingerprint
      $scope.uploading -= 1
    )

  $scope.cancel = ->
    for picture in $scope.pictures
      if picture.progress < 100 and not picture.upload.aborted
        picture.upload.abort()
        picture.upload.aborted = true
    $scope.closeModal()
    $scope.pictures = []
    $scope.uploading = 0
    $scope.successUpload = 0

  $scope.progressClass = (picture)->
    if picture.upload.aborted
      'progress-bar-warning'
    else if picture.progress == 100 and picture.errors?
      'progress-bar-danger'
    else if picture.progress == 100
      'progress-bar-success'
    else
      ''

]
```

Could you explain to me how can I keep the value of `{{position}}` between the views?

**EDIT:**

Well, I edited a service and added the position:

```
App.factory 'newPictures', ->
  return {
    pictures: []
    position: 'last'

    add: (picture)->
      @pictures.push(picture)

    clear: ->
      @pictures = []

  }
```

Then, in the directive, I just added the `$scope.position`

```
$scope.editView = ->
   $scope.pictures    = newPictures.pictures
   $scope.position    = newPictures.position
   $scope.editPicture = $scope.pictures[0]
   $scope.view        = 'edit'
```

in my controller:

```
$scope.setPosition = (position) ->
   $scope.position = position
   newPictures.position = position
```

And I edited my view to add ng-change:

```
  .row
    .col-xs-4
      p.pull-left= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.position')
      .radio-inline
        label
          input type="radio" ng-model="position" data-ng-change="setPosition('first')" value="first"= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.first_position')
      .radio-inline
        label
          input type="radio" ng-model="position" data-ng-change="setPosition('last')" value="last"= t('views.shared.picture_upload_modal.last_position')
```

I'm not sure if it's a clean way to do what I want but it works

Comment: you are not using different views, you are using the same view which has the same controller so your whole view has the value of position on it try using ng-show instead of ng-if in the line 
'.modal-content data-ng-if="view == 'edit'"'
'.modal-content data-ng-show="view == 'edit'"'

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GauravSingh but I still have the same problem: `{{position}}`is not defined at the end

Comment: and when you don't use curly braces around the position?

Comment: Without braces I just have a string param 'position' instead of the value of position

Comment: is your position variable is getting changed in your controller when you toggle the radio buttons??

Comment: I can see the value in the console with `$scope.setPosition = (position) -> console.log position` but only in the upload view

Comment: please upload your HTML in readable format with proper indentation and brackets

Comment: Thank for your help @GauravSingh but I succeeded by use a service, I'm going to edit my post with the solution